# How to find SHA1 in Cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, sha1, cordova-3

So... I need to get a SHA1 key. I'm not a Java fan, so I'm creating my app in Cordova but I need the SHA1 to register it in Google's Developer Console. Does someone know where it is? I tried importing the project in Android studio but still couldn't find anything...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Windows you have to create it using command prompt.First go to your java bin directory via the cmd like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin,then type

```
keytool -list -v -keystore c:\users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

For Mac users go to terminal ,then type

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```